# Parametrize Root Element of XML body In jmeter

Tags: java, xml, jmeter, blazemeter

I want to parametrize Root Element as a whole in HTTP Sampler, as the number of  attributes changes for different event codes. When I try to parametrize using CSV it does not take all the attributes(ExtractedValue.JPG)[Value in Image Is Extracted which is incomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW2ux.jpg). The value which was supposed to be extracted is as follows:

(ActuallvaluetoBeExtracted.JPG)[This is the Value which is supposed to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm6Ar.jpg)

Can someone please help to identify why it is unable to extract all the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use one of the following:

1. If you can split the data into multiple files or use the same data from single file - use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function
2. If you can put each JSON Payload to new line you can go for:

   - CSV Data Set Config with `\n` as the delimiter
   - [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) article for comprehensive information on above and other JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change delimiter in `Csv data set config` to any other delimiter except `,` as you want to pass a string which consist of multiple commas from your csv file. So change this to `;` or any other symbol. It will resolve your issue. Please refer below snapshot for better understanding.[image]

Comment: Still Unable to Extract ..extracted Value ("     {""AttributeName"": ""AccountName"",""AttributeValue"": ""Savings Account""},)  Expected : (      {"AttributeName": "AccountName","AttributeValue": "Savings Account"},
      {"AttributeName": "MinDepositReqdAmnt","AttributeValue": "£5000"},
      {"AttributeName": "FirstName","AttributeValue": "Ryan"},
      {"AttributeName": "LastName","AttributeValue": "Gates"},
      {"AttributeName": "CompanyName","AttributeValue": "zz"},
   {"AttributeName": "OriginatingBank","AttributeValue": "zz"})

Comment: Now i am able to extract ( {"AttributeName": "AccountName","AttributeValue": "Savings Account"},) but as expected after "Savings Account"}, it should extract ({"AttributeName": "MinDepositReqdAmnt"....) ...the setting which i have used is Delimiter : ;, Allow Quoted Data :False, Recycle on EOF:True, Stop Thread On EOF : False ... DOes any 1 have solution for this?

Comment: do u want extract complete details in one iteration than remove new lines i.e. write all values in single line or use \n as a delimiter.